# Question Mark (?) in Apache Tomcat proxy_ajp.conf causing proxy to fail

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat

We had directives in our proxy_ajp.conf similiar to below, which would give us a 404.

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /test https://www.purple.com/test?
ProxyPassReverse /test https://www.purple.com/test?
```

When we (finally) removed just the question marks and it worked. I can't find any reference to the question mark being a reserved char or anything. Question is, why does this happen? My guess is that if I wanted to include the question mark, it would need to be escaped. I don't have a test bed at the moment to play around with (this was our production proxy that had the issue).

Just for fun (although it doesn't matter for the question), the original intent was to build queries in code without including the question mark, which once we found the issue to be the question marks, we now prepend the question mark to the query.